# Why does 6.53 + 8 = 14.530000000000001 in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, math, rounding, rounding-error

I know it's probably due to some sort of rounding technique, but clearly 6.53 + 8 should only equal 14.53. My questions are, why is this happening, and how can I get an accurate sum?

```
var x = 6.53 + 8;
console.log(x);// 14.530000000000001
```

Comment: It's because 6.53 cannot be represented exactly in an [IEEE 754 binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decimal point numbers are represented differently in a computer...and have this problem..u can have that happen in many programming languages...round your number to a certain precision...as long as you don't do advanced computation with JavaScript you will be fine. More info.  https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_numbers.asp

Comment: I used `parseFloat(eval(equation_string).toPrecision(10));` and it works well. I'm making a calculator program for fun and ran into this issue.

Answer (score 3):

It is normal behavior with `JS`, Try to use `toFixed(2)` like this

```
var x = 6.53 + 8;
console.log(x.toFixed(2));
```